# Input Data Not Stored in Database using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a table in my PHP page inside the HTML block of a PHP. Here is the code below for the table.

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Promotional Price</td>
    <td>Regular Price</td>
    <td>Stacking</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="product"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="pp1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="rp1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="stacking"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id ="div1">
<input type="button"  value="Submit"  onClick="PostData();"/><br/>
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript for the same to send it to another PHP is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PostData() {




    // 1. Create XHR instance - Start
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }
    // 1. Create XHR instance - End

    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start
    var product = document.getElementById("product").value;
    var pp1 = document.getElementById("pp1").value;
    var rp1 = document.getElementById("rp1").value;
    var stacking = document.getElementById("stacking").value;

    // var image = document.getElementById("image").value;
    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - Start
xhr.open('POST', 'report.php');
    //xhr.open('POST', 'config.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("product=" + product + "pp1=" + pp1 + "rp1=" + rp1 + "stacking=" + stacking);
}

</script>
```

and the PHP to store the value to the database is as below.

```
    <?php  
    //Updated after the answer from AnikIslam
    $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "testing";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_report (product,pp1, rp1,stacking) VALUES ('$product', '$pp1', '$rp1','$stacking')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Successful";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
    ?>
```

As seen in the screenshot, I have 2 blocks to enter the data. Now the data is entered into the database from the first block only. I want the data to be stored from the second block to the second row in the database. How can it be achieved.

[image]

Comment: try doing a var_dump($_POST); to see if you are receiving any data at all

Comment: why this line is out :  `//xhr.open('POST', 'config.php');`

Comment: is this right way `if(isset($_POST['product'],$_POST['pp1'],$_POST['rp1'],$_POST['stacking']))`

Comment: @Satya where it should be done??

Comment: @Shehary I did it before for others and it works perfectly fine

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi coz it is not relevant

Comment: @Puttaa do it in your php

Comment: @Satya like this _$product = var_dump($_POST["product"]);_ ??

Comment: if it's not relevent then how come your request will know where to hit and which verb will use to hit ?

Comment: @Puttaa , no it is like var_dump($_POST); that's it

Comment: @Satya No, it doesnt return anything.

Comment: @Puttaa if you don't know how to var_dump the $_POST .. Just  use the print _r function . print_r($_POST)  on top your if condition. and post the output.. or check the form data in the network tab of chrome .So you can check whether the data is present or not..

Comment: @JijoJohn its working now.

Comment: @Satya Thanks. _var_dump($_POST);_ works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
 xhr.send("product=" + product + "&pp1=" + pp1 + "&rp1=" + rp1 + "&stacking=" + stacking);
```

For Php Part

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "testing";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_report (product,pp1, rp1,stacking) VALUES ('$product', '$pp1', '$rp1','$stacking')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Successful";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

**Edit**

each form's should have unique id

pass block name in submit button

Like this

first block

```
onClick="PostData('Block1');"
```

second block

```
onClick="PostData('Block2');"
```

JS

```
function PostData(block){



  if(block==="Block1"){
     // fetech data from block1
  }
  else if(block==="Block2"){
     // fetech data from block2
  }

}
```

Comment: Now it says **No Database Selected**

Comment: now it's passing data to your php file :) .. please provide the code of config.php file

Comment: You are mixing mysql with mysqli .. both are different things. I have updated my answer . please check.

Comment: Works completely fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85372/discussion-between-puttaa-and-anik-islam-abhi).

Comment: I hope you can see the screenshot. Now when I am trying to enter the data into the second block, it still stores the data from the first block. I want it to stored in different row in the database.

Comment: But the number of blocks are not fixed, It depend on the data fetched from the database.

Comment: name it dynamically and pass it dynamically

Comment: I have a counter that counts the number of the blocks dynamically. But i dont know how to use it to store the data to the database.

Comment: that's a different question how store value from dynamically created form. Stackoverflow policy says that ask that separately

Comment: It doesnt allow me to POST the question before 90mins.. :)

Comment: Please have a look at this question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870401/store-different-value-in-the-database-from-the-forms-created-dynamically-using-p)